# Textbox on changes directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

What is the equivalent for jQuery change event on every input in Angular2?
Example:

```
$("input").on('change', function() { 
   console.log("*"); 
});
```

Comment: Create a directive with a selector of `input` and register the `change` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle it using Directive as said by Igor as below

1. create a directive using

   ```
   import { Directive, HostListener, Renderer, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
   @Directive({
       selector: '[change]'
   })
   export class ChangeDirective{

       constructor(
           private renderer: Renderer,
           private el: ElementRef
       ){}

       @HostListener('keyup') onKeyUp() {

        console.log('some thing key upped')

       }
   }
   ```
2. Import it to the main.ts
3. Add to declarations of the module

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/iwkGjqLO1AKEffVlzKmp?p=preview)**