# Prevent user from typing certain characters into a text input field

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm not sure what this is called. It's really simple. I tried using a pipe, but I got an error. I'm looking for something as simple as:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="order.name | lettersOnlyPipe"/>
```

That doesn't work. What can I do that would accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want to prevent them from being entered? Or filter them out after they are entered? If the later, then a pipe will work. If the former, then a pattern or directive may be your best option.

Comment: Take a look on [text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask).

Answer (score 2):

With the recent Angular 4 release, you can use the `pattern` attribute to restrict characters as mentioned in this [feature](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/38cb526)

```
<input [(ngModel)]="order.name" pattern="" />
```

In other case, you should handle it using custom directive. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400175/textbox-on-changes-directive-angular2/42400391#42400391) for a sample.

Comment: I tried using the pattern attribute like you pointed out. It made the field show an error, but didn't prevent the user from entering characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for this is your own directive.

**Some simple ideas to get you going:**

- your directive monitors the input event on its host element
- on every input event, you check whether the input value is valid, if not, you set your input back to its old value

or alternatively,
* monitor the keydown event and on each keydown, check if the key is a valid key - if not, set your input back to its old value

That's the basic approach. You can look at the [highlight directive example in the angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) as a guide to get going.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a similar [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47474444/9003811)
here, you'll just need to change regex (remove numbers and perhaps arabic characters from it). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
input [name]="fullName" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*" ngModel
```

In angular 4 you can use Pattern attribute and specify pattern as `= [a-zA-Z ]` for only letters.

Answer (score 1):

Using the pattern attribute do not prevent entering anything inside the input field. It will just mark it as invalid.
You must use a Directive to do so.
Here is a simple example that prevent entering anything but positive number into a input field:

```
import {Directive, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[dsancNumeroPositif]'
})
export class NumeroPositifDirective {

  acceptedCharacters: string[] = ['.', ',', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onInput(event: KeyboardEvent): void
  {
    if (!this.acceptedCharacters.includes(event.key)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

}
```