# How to restrict special characters in the input field using Angular 2 / Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I am new to Angular 2. I need to prevent special characters from being typed in the input field. If I type alphanumerics, it must accept them, while special characters should be blocked. Can anyone help please.

I am sharing the code here.

In HTML:

```html
<md-input-container>
   <input type="text" (ngModelChange)="omit_special_char($event)" mdInput name="name" [(ngModel)]="company.name" placeholder="Company Name" #name="ngModel" minlength="3" required>
</md-input-container>
```

In TS:

```
public e: any;

omit_special_char(val)
{
   var k;
   document.all ? k = this.e.keyCode : k = this.e.which;
   return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
}
```

Comment: you can use ng-pattern for it. it is very simple and useful

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You were doing everything right. Just the function needs to be changed a bit. You were using ngModelChange to bind event which is not there. You can use **keypress** event handler as shown below.

**HTML**

```
   <md-input-container>
    <input type="text" (keypress)="omit_special_char($event)" mdInput name="name" [(ngModel)]="company.name" placeholder="Company Name" #name="ngModel" minlength="3" required>
    </md-input-container>
```

**Component**

```
omit_special_char(event)
{   
   var k;  
   k = event.charCode;  //         k = event.keyCode;  (Both can be used)
   return((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57)); 
}
```

"event" is the object of "$event" itself which you have passed earlier. Try this one, it will surely work with angular2.

Comment: Your solution is fine but not working for copy and paste .. Thankful to you if u give solution for that

Comment: @Abhijeet It was coded to solve the problem of questioner so might need to be altered by your need.

Comment: @MaulikModi yes right .. but I problem is solved I fixed it by myself :)

Comment: One problem with this approach will be when user will paste data it wont work. You should call function on blur too.

Comment: I'm working with ionic angular. Can you help me to achieve same functionality with android?

Answer (score 27):

I combined several answers from this and other posts and created my custom directive for handling both manual input and pasting data.

The directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
    @Directive({
        selector: '[appInputRestriction]'
    })
    export class InputRestrictionDirective {
        inputElement: ElementRef;

        @Input('appInputRestriction') appInputRestriction: string;
        arabicRegex = '[\u0600-\u06FF]';

        constructor(el: ElementRef) {
            this.inputElement = el;
        }

        @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeyPress(event) {
            if (this.appInputRestriction === 'integer') {
                this.integerOnly(event);
            } else if (this.appInputRestriction === 'noSpecialChars') {
                this.noSpecialChars(event);
            }
        }

        integerOnly(event) {
            const e = <KeyboardEvent>event;
            if (e.key === 'Tab' || e.key === 'TAB') {
                return;
            }
            if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (e.keyCode === 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+C
                (e.keyCode === 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+V
                (e.keyCode === 86 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+X
                (e.keyCode === 88 && e.ctrlKey === true)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            }
            if (['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'].indexOf(e.key) === -1) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }

        noSpecialChars(event) {
            const e = <KeyboardEvent>event;
            if (e.key === 'Tab' || e.key === 'TAB') {
                return;
            }
            let k;
            k = event.keyCode;  // k = event.charCode;  (Both can be used)
            if ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k === 8 || k === 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57)) {
                return;
            }
            const ch = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
            const regEx = new RegExp(this.arabicRegex);
            if (regEx.test(ch)) {
                return;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        @HostListener('paste', ['$event']) onPaste(event) {
            let regex;
            if (this.appInputRestriction === 'integer') {
                regex = /[0-9]/g;
            } else if (this.appInputRestriction === 'noSpecialChars') {
                regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9\u0600-\u06FF]/g;
            }
            const e = <ClipboardEvent>event;
            const pasteData = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
            let m;
            let matches = 0;
            while ((m = regex.exec(pasteData)) !== null) {
                // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
                if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
                    regex.lastIndex++;
                }
                // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
                m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
                    matches++;
                });
            }
            if (matches === pasteData.length) {
                return;
            } else {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }

    }
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text" appInputRestriction="noSpecialChars" class="form-control-full" [(ngModel)]="noSpecialCharsModel" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [disabled]="isSelected" required>

<input type="text" appInputRestriction="integer" class="form-control-full" [(ngModel)]="integerModel" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

This is actually my first stackoverflow answer so I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks I used your code, however I changed it a bit since your code was blocking any paste data if it was invalid (containing special chars). However on my side I wanted to remove the special chars, so I replaced a slight portion of your code and it works great. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

angular2 code sample.

```
<input type="text" pattern="/[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}/i">
```

or

```
<md-input-container>
<input type="text" (keypress)="omit_special_char($event)" mdInput name="name" [(ngModel)]="company.name" placeholder="Company Name" #name="ngModel" minlength="3" required>
</md-input-container>

omit_special_char(val)
{
   var k;
    document.all ? k = this.e.keyCode : k = this.e.which;
    return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
}
```

here is the working sample in pure javascript because angular2/typescript wont support in StackOverflow.

```js
function omit_special_char(e) {
    var k;
    document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
    return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return omit_special_char(event)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replying. I will try and tell you

Comment: sorry it is not working with me. Il paste what i tried with my code. I had updated my code please have a look

Comment: e is the event. you can run above code it should work. based on that modify it in your typescript

Comment: Ya the above snippet is working the same way i wanted. I am trying but not getting

Comment: i can show demo in angular 1 but you want angular 2 alone?

Comment: ya i need in angular2 only

Comment: try this... updated my answer. try with patterns. hope it should work for you

Comment: ya will try and tell

Comment: No sorry, it is not taking

Answer (score 3):

You can use pattern in input tag 
Works fine with angular7.

for validating special characters

```
                <input #Name="ngModel" type="text" name="Name" required maxlength="256" minlength="2"
                    [(ngModel)]="Name" class="validate form-control" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$">
                </div>
```

allowing Space
use =>
                   pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$">

full usage with showing Validation Message :

```
                <label for="Name" class="form-label">{{"Name" | localize}}*</label>

                <div class="input-group"><input #dashboardName="ngModel" type="text" name="Name" required maxlength="256" minlength="2"
                    [(ngModel)]="Name" class="validate form-control" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$">
                </div>
                <validation-messages [formCtrl]="Name"></validation-messages>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also made used of Regex pattern

```
<md-input-container>
<input type="text" (ngModelChange)="omit_special_char($event)" mdInput name="name" [(ngModel)]="company.name" placeholder="Company Name" #name="ngModel" minlength="3" required>
</md-input-container>

public omit_special_char(e: any) {
    try {
        let k;
        if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$/.test(e.key)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    } catch (e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can go with ng-change attribute then call function in javascript and validate there..

```
<md-input-container> 
<input type="text" mdInput ng-change="myValidationFunction()" name="name" placeholder="Company Name" #name="ngModel" ng-model="name" minlength="3" required>
</md-input-container>
```

In javaScript:

```
myValidateFunction() 
{
  if ($scope.name.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")) {
     return true;
  } 
  else {
     return false
  }
}
```

Based on function result you can do what you want ...validate or disallow or if you want to show any CSS msg then you can

Comment: Thanks for replying i will try

Comment: $scope is not present in angular2

Comment: you can use 'this' instead

Comment: I got this error :There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("ype="text" (ngModelChange)="myValidationFunction()" mdInput  name="name" placeholder="Company Name" [ERROR ->]#name="ngModel" ng-model="name" minlength="3" required>

Answer (score -2):

You can use html5 pattern validator as

```
<input type="text" (ngModelChange)="omit_special_char($event)" mdInput name="name" [(ngModel)]="company.name" placeholder="Company Name" #name="ngModel" minlength="3" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]">
```

Add novalidate to form and then you can display error for same as

```
<div *ngIf="name?.errors.pattern && name.dirty && name.invalid">Error Message</div>
```