# How to disallow bad input for an angular material input field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a simple angular material input field

```
<form [formGroup]="parentFG">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input [formControlName]="CALCULATOR_INPUT" matInput placeholder="" autocomplete="off" (keyup)="updateInput($event)">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

With a form control and validator that only allows unsigned integers

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let formControl = new FormControl('', UIntValidatorDirective.validateFunc);

    this.parentFG.addControl(this.CALCULATOR_INPUT, formControl);
  }
```

The validator works and highlights the input with red when invalid input is entered. However, I don't want to allow the user to enter invalid input in the first place. Is there a way to disallow invalid characters or strings from ever being placed in the input field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a `regex` filter function and add desired behavior.

**basic example**: You can combine this with `Rxjs` to check the input on every keypress or a custom time interval.

```
    RemoveInvalidString(formInputValue){

        if (!(/^\d+$/.test(formInputValue))) { //unsigned integer?

            console.log("removing input value", formInputValue)

            formInputValue = ''

        }

    }
```

**related posts**: [How to restrict special characters in the input field using angular2/ typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072369/how-to-restrict-special-characters-in-the-input-field-using-angular2-typescript)