# Angular 2 ngModel inside a function

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to pass a ngModel to a function and get the change,

I don't know the way to use.

this is what I got now:

```
          <ion-input text-right
               formControlName="monday"
               type="number" pattern="[0-9]*"
               placeholder="00.00"
               [(ngModel)]="monday"
               (keypress)="onChange(monday)">
           </ion-input>

           <ion-input text-right
               formControlName="tuesday"
               type="number" pattern="[0-9]*"
               placeholder="00.00"
               [(ngModel)]="tueasday"
               (keypress)="onChange(tuesday)">
           </ion-input>
```

.... and so on...

Then in my page.ts I got

```
monday: string = '';
tuesday: string = '';
etc...

onChange(input: string){
//I want the input to correspond to my ngModel so it gets updated
    input = this.clientAction.transformInput(input);
}
```

I don't want to do:

```
this.monday = this.clientAction.transformInput(input);
```

Because as you may think I got all the day of the week so I don't want to have a function for every day like:

```
onChangeMonday(){};
onChangeTuesday(){};
```

I need something dynamic.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

**[SOLUTION]** @AJT_82

instead of using my ngModel and trying to update it, the solution was to access the controls from the form.

in your page.html

```
      <ion-input text-right
           formControlName="monday"
           type="number" pattern="[0-9]*"
           placeholder="00.00"
           [(ngModel)]="monday"
           (keypress)="onChange(monday, 'monday')">
       </ion-input>
```

then in your page.ts

```
onChange(input: string, day: string){
this.rateForm.controls[day].setValue(this.clientAction.transformInput(input));
}
```

works like a charm now !!
**Thanks @AJT_82**

Comment: You'd have to share some more code, I'm not sure what should be happening here: `input = this.clientAction.transformInput(input);`

Comment: Hi, AJT_82, input is the name of the variable, but because I passed in the example monday by doing input = this.clientAction.transformInput(input); I wanted that it will to do the same as this.monday = this.clientAction.transformInput(input); where input = monday so it reassign the result of my request to the value monday which is my ngModel
Thanks

Comment: I just edit my question to explain better

Comment: Okay, now I understand better :) But still not sure what `input = this.clientAction.transformInput(input);` is supposed to do? Do you need to use it somewhere. You also have your changed values saved in your formControls, you could make use of them as well instead. Don't know what the change event is supposed to do therefore I asked what that is for :)

Comment: the request `this.clientAction.transformInput(input)` return a string formatted, that I need to reinject inside the ngModel.
input is not present in my code because I'm looking for how to connect the return of my request to `this.input` meaning `this.day_of_the_week` which correspond to a variable in my script.

To understand better if I change to `this.monday = this.clientAction.transformInput(input);` instead of `input = this.clientAction.transformInput(input);` it will change the ngModel for monday but I will need to create 7 functions for each day repeating the same code everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a form, I would suggest that you skip the `ngModels` altogether and make use of the form you have. Still a bit unsure about what `this.clientAction.transformInput(input)` is supposed to do, transform the values somehow, as you explained. You should be able to incorporate this, perhaps when you submit the form? Anyway, as said, you have your form values safely stored in the object created by the form, which would for you look something like this:

```ts
{
  "monday":null,
  "tuesday":null,
  "wednesday":null,
  // ... and so on
}
```

When you type in your fields you can capture every keypress with `valueChanges`, where you can access the complete form:

```ts
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(res => {
  console.log("all form values: ", res) // here is an object with all your form values
})
```

When you need, you can also access each form control by, here accessing monday:

```ts
  console.log(this.myForm.controls['monday'].value)
```

So this get's rid of the hassle to use `ngModel` for each form value.

So these are a couple of ways you can intercept the values and then "transform" them at some point, when you want/need to. Probably best place to do so, is when submitting form, loop the values and transform them. And this is totally dynamic, as you wished for, and do not need 7 functions to transform each form control! ;)

Hope this helps you, and here's a plunker (check the console as well).

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/56qw7cnH9c2JbyY1Lop2?p=preview)

Comment: thanks @ajt_82 all good!! I edited my post too, thanks again for your help, better understanding now.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using ngModel why do you want  to pass the same in to function

```
<ion-input text-right
               formControlName="monday"
               type="number" pattern="[0-9]*"
               placeholder="00.00"
               [(ngModel)]="monday"
               (keypress)="onChange()">
           </ion-input>
```

and handle using the ngModel itself as

```
onChange(){
    input = this.clientAction.transformInput(this.monday);
}
```

Update 1:

I got your are looking transform the textbox value as the user types it. 
**[Check Custom Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400175/textbox-on-changes-directive-angular2/42400391#42400391)**

Comment: the thing is by doing this I need to create 7 functions for all the days (as I got an input for every day) of the week. What I want is one function for all the days, which handle the ngModel and return the value changed to the appropriated input.

Comment: I didnt get you can you elaborate